# How to Change background color of the cell if the cell is being edited

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, background-color

I have two datagridview cells, grid1 and grid2. am i loading the files to both grid, i have used the version of the file. every time when i Save/edit a file it increment a file version by 1 from 5, which means it will be 6,7,8,9 etc.

file version starts from 5. Increment it is working with no problem

I want to change the background color of the cell if i loaded the file and edit, from that cell edited, it must change the background color to yellow.

1. Load existing file
2. Edit the file
3. Background color of the edited cell must change to yellow
4. Save the file and clear the color (this is working)

I have tried this but,it is highlighting the color when i created the file. i only need it to change background cell color only on editing the file.

my code:

```
    int version_Number = 5;
    string _OriginalValue;
    private void Grid1_CellBeginEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _OriginalValue = Grid1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured.\nError message: " + ex.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


    #region Grid2_CellEndEdit_1
    private void Grid2_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = Grid2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (cell.Value.ToString() != _OriginalValue)
            {
                if (version_Number >= 1000)
                {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
```

Comment: There is no shame using a flag ever now and then. Set it to `bool loading=true` before you have loaded the data and afterwards to false. Test it in the `CellEndEdit` event!

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: My answer assumes that your coloring code is working, except for the problem with the loading..

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the part that colors the cell in the cellformating event, a sample i tried is as below

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (cell.Value  != null)
            {
                if (cell.Value.ToString() != _OriginalValue)
                {

                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                }   
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a flag to stop the coloring from happening during the loading of the data:

```
int version_Number = 5;
string _OriginalValue;

bool loading = false;
```

You somewhere load the data; now set and reset the flag there:

```
loding = true;
yourDataLoadingCodeHere;
loading = false;
```

Now, if they otherwise work you can simply abort your two events:

```
private void Grid1_CellBeginEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (loading) return;

    try
    {
        _OriginalValue = Grid1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured.\nError message: " + 
        ex.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}



private void Grid2_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (loading) return;

   try
   {
     DataGridViewCell cell = Grid2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
     if (cell.Value.ToString() != _OriginalValue)
     {
        if (version_Number >= 1000)
        {
           cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }  
    ..
    ..
```